# Spring console app, load property file from outside of JAR

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm using Spring in a console Java application. 
My application will be deployed like:

```
folder/myJar.jar
folder/db/connection.properties
```

How do I load the *connection.properties* in a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in application context?

I have tried

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="db/connection.properties"/>
</bean>
```

but it won't work.

I need it this way for my database username/password and other details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the prefix `file:` to the location value:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:db/connection.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that start from the root of the file system?  So it must be stored in /db/connection.properties or C:/db/connection.properties?  I think you want to go relative to the classpath.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It is relative to project folder, @kmb385. `file:/db/properties` would mean what you referred to in UNIX/Windows file systems respectively.

Comment: just found it in the spring docs, A FileSystemResource that is not attached to a FileSystemApplicationContext (that is, a
FileSystemApplicationContext is not the actual ResourceLoader) will treat absolute vs.
relative paths as you would expect. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, while
absolute paths are relative to the root of the filesystem.

Comment: Yeah, here: static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch05s07.html#resources-filesystemresource-caveats. So, it's always relative to the current directory, the directory from where the java command will be run.

Answer (score -1):

Specify that the file is on the classpath in the value attribute

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:db/connection.properties"/>
</bean>
```